# PromiseKit - Optional promise with reload first promise

Tags: promisekit

I read all documentation but I don't response my question with successfull.
I have this scenario

- I call the authenticated api point

  1. If the response is 200 to 299 I fullfill
  2. If the response is 401 I call the api for refresh the token

If i refreshed the API token I need to re-call the first api point (for recovery the needed data).
Can you help me with this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use **recursion** for you needs. Using PromiseKit you can do awesome things. See my flow with refresh token request below. I expect that the code below is self-documented.

```
// Define here your errors 
enum MyErrors: Swift.Error {
    case unauthorized
    case unknown
}

// Here is your primary function for retrieving remote data    
func fetchRemoteData() {
    self.primaryRequest()
        .then { data in
            return self.parsePrimaryRequest(response: data)
        }
        .done { parsedResult in
            // do something here if all chaining is success
        }
        .recover { primaryRequestError in // this is your case for refresh token
            if case MyErrors.unauthorized = primaryRequestError { // if not authorized
                self.refreshTokenRequest()
                    .then { data in
                        return self.parseRefreshToken(data: data)
                    }
                    .done { token in
                        // do someting with token, save it in secure store (keychain)
                        self.fetchRemoteData()
                    }
                    .catch { refreshTokenError in
                    // refresh token request has failed
                }
            }
            else {
                throw primaryRequestError
            }
        }
        .catch { primaryRequestError in
            // here if error during request
    }
}

func primaryRequest() -> Promise<Data> {
    return Promise { seal in
        // here you execure the request
        // ...
        // ...
        let responseData = Data() // here you get data from URLSessionTask etc
        let yourRequestStatusCode = 401 // take status code


        let successCodes = Array(200...299) // define success codes
        let authorizationErrorCode = 401 // define status code which requires performing refresh token request
        if successCodes.contains(yourRequestStatusCode) {
            return seal.fulfill(responseData)
        } else if yourRequestStatusCode == authorizationErrorCode {
            throw MyErrors.unauthorized
        } else {
            throw MyErrors.unknown
        }
    }
}

func parsePrimaryRequest(response: Data) -> Promise<String> {
    return Promise { seal in
        // here you parse response
        // ...
        // ...

        let parsedObject = "Awesome result"
        seal.fulfill(parsedObject)
    }
}

func refreshTokenRequest() -> Promise<Data> {
    return Promise { seal in
        // here you execure the request to refresh token
        // ...
        // ...
        let responseData = Data() // here you get data from URLSessionTask etc
        let yourRequestStatusCode = 401 // take status code


        let successCodes = Array(200...299) // define success codes for refresh token request
        if successCodes.contains(yourRequestStatusCode) {
            return seal.fulfill(responseData)
        } else {
            throw MyErrors.unknown
        }
    }
}

func parseRefreshToken(data: Data) -> Promise<String> {
    return Promise { seal in
        // here you parse response
        // ...
        // ...

        let parsedObject = "00000000-00000000-00000000-00000000"
        seal.fulfill(parsedObject)
    }
}
```